# ProgressDialog freeze when adding layout in view

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog

Progress dialog freeze when adding a large view in layout from onPost of AsyncTask. We have to add a dynamic layout so we have called that from onPost,( On calling that from doInBackground error occure, So we have called that from opPost) But now the progress dialog freeze when loading that layout.

Please Help...

I have created a separated class and called that class method

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
        {

            eLayout=new ExcelLayout(viewScreenActivity);
            eLayout.LinearLayoutXLSView(ROW_HEIGHT, COL_WIDTH, ROW_Title_Width,NUM_COLS, NUM_ROWS, cols, rows, data);

            progressdialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Progress dialog freeze and disappear after task completed.

Comment: if you do not want to dismiss the dialog in `onPostExecute()` method then why are you called this function `progressdialog.dismiss();` inside this method?

Answer (score 1):

This problem raises when there is a huge process such as drawing a view happens in the main UI thread. The progress dialogs are very light weight process and when some other process takes priority then they just stop there without rotating (in simple) which makes it looks like it has hanged. But the actual reason is, there is some other process which takes more priority than showing the progress dialog.

In your case it is the View creation which takes priority. So  what you have to do is, dismiss the dialog before starting to draw the layout.

But if you are looking for a way to show a progress dialog while you draw your view i am afraid it is not possible, from my experience so far.

**EDIT**

it is very much clear that your main UI does a lot of work. YOu can try this but I am not sure how far this will work. Instead of just calling the methods immediately after the progressdialog.dismiss(), you could use the dismiss listener and call the methods from there. For example,

```
progressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){

  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

   eLayout=new ExcelLayout(viewScreenActivity);
        eLayout.LinearLayoutXLSView(ROW_HEIGHT, COL_WIDTH, ROW_Title_Width,NUM_COLS, NUM_ROWS, cols, rows, data);
  }});
```

So this gets called only when the progress dialog's progressdialog.dismiss(); is called. So it should work probably.

Comment: Before adding the view i called dismiss function but still app is getting freezed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..... I have changed as your edited reply, But app will not work for some time after dialog dismiss(Due to loading of layout). I have changed the way to implementing layout now.